# How to get Edge to respect hosts file redirect?

Tags: redirection, microsoft-edge

I cannot get Edge to respect my hosts file redirections.

Initially I couldn't get the redirected page to resolve whatsoever so had to change hosts redirect from (as an example) 10.255.22.117 dct.nd.com to 10.255.22.117 https://dct.nd.com which does resolve but does not redirect.

Tried the following two fixes with no luck:

- [Revisiting Fiddler and Win8+ Immersive applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fiddler/2011/12/10/revisiting-fiddler-and-win8-immersive-applications/)
- [Microsoft Edge FAQ: How can I debug localhost?](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/#how-can-i-debug-localhost)

Comment: `https://dct.nd.com` is not a valid hostname. It is a HTTP Uniform Resource Locator (URL) although part of it is a hostname. So it's not surprising that doesn't work.

Comment: but redirecting 'dct.nd.com' doesn't resolve at all, not until I include 'https://' does the page load (albeit without redirect), so I guess you're correct that it doesn't work so any thoughts on what will?